# Web Assembly and Rust: cargo build vs wasm-pack

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo, wasm-pack

Some examples of building wasm use `cargo build` (like the examples in the book Programming WebAssembly)

```
cargo build --release --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

And others use,

```
wasm-pack build --target web ....
```

What's the different between these two methods of building a project?

Answer (score 7):

Wasm-pack is a bigger convenience application that provides more than simply building the Rust code.

Amongst other things wasm-pack provides:

- Building Rust projects to WebAssembly (equivalent to `cargo build --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown ...`)
- Binding to Node.js
- Publishing results to the npm registry.
- Creating new projects (like `cargo new`)

> This tool seeks to be a one-stop shop for building and working with rust- generated WebAssembly that you would like to interop with JavaScript, in the browser or with Node.js. wasm-pack helps you build rust-generated WebAssembly packages that you could publish to the npm registry, or otherwise use alongside any javascript packages in workflows that you already use, such as webpack or greenkeeper. [1](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-pack/book/)